# Download Content From External URL and save in db with Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services

This isn't webservices. I want to pass a url to a controller and then have it fetch the html from that page. Then store the information in a db.

What do you think? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Re:"What do you think?"  I think, it's a good idea!

Comment: lol, was that an answer. I truly appreciate the support but I need help :)

Comment: Why do you say "This isn't webservices." and tag the post `web-services`?

Comment: Good point. I guess my logic was because I didn't wan to get a web services answer if that makes any sense. but now than I think about it adding it draws more attention that not adding it so not to smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
html = %x[curl #{params[:url]}]
```

That will execute the system curl command and save the result (this is, the content extracted from the url) in the variable `html`. Then you can make hot cakes with that string if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

yes
hints: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Standard_Library/OpenURI

and then use some ORM or use the mysql drivers directly.

Comment: what do you mean use some ORM or use the mysql drivers directly

Answer (score 1):

When I read your post, the first thing I thought of was Watir @ http://watir.com/

> Watir is a family of Ruby libraries
>   but it supports your app no matter
>   what technology it is developed in.
>   They support Internet Explorer on
>   Windows, Firefox on Windows, Mac and
>   Linux, Safari on Mac, Chrome on
>   Windows and Flash testing with
>   Firefox.
>
> Like other programming languages, Ruby
>   gives you the power to connect to
>   databases, read data files and
>   spreadsheets, export XML, and
>   structure your code as reusable
>   libraries. Unlike other programming
>   languages, Ruby is concise and often a
>   joy to read.

You can easily grab HTML and then populate it to a database, excel, etc.